# Trying to make a discord but I keep getting the error "required is not defined"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, requirejs, require

I'm really new at this and I'm trying to get the bot to come online but no matter what I do the error message comes up, I also downloaded requirejs but it doesn't seem to be working. basically, I have no idea what I'm doing and need help.

```
const {Clients, Intents} = require(discord.js);
const TOKEN = '************************************************'
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Inents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLags.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ]
});




client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}')
});
client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: How are you running this JS file?

Comment: im running it on visual studios with node :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things. Don't give out your token on public websites. Discord has probably dmed you saying you gave out your token here, but still. I'd recommend creating a .env file with the 'dotenv' package (if you know what that is.) just to keep your token private.

On your 5th line, `Intents` has a typo, it says `Inents`. So, make sure that's fixed, and same with the 6th line. It should be `FLAGS` not `FLags`

The reason "require" isn't defined is because you need to put discord.js in quotations like this.

`const {Clients, Intents} = require('discord.js');`

If you have any other errors, feel free to reply with it. Have a great day.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put discord.js in quotes like this:

```js
const {Clients, Intents} = require("discord.js");
```